# Text React native interaction on each word, longPress to highlight the Text. #31187

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text

**Description**:
I have a future that handles by text, I want users can interact with each word, my app will show a modal to note comments for this word and this word will be a highlight. please see the image below:

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic5ca.png)

**React Native version:**
0.63

**Steps To Reproduce**
Make a Text In React Native.

**Expected Results**:
Users can interact with each word. and highlight it when select.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far? Please post your code and the problems you are facing so the chaps here can help you out.

Comment: thanks! my code is only a simple Text element in React Native. For Example <Text> Hello world </Text>  and I want to handle some action as my Description. can you give me a lib or some code to handle Text? Please see my img in the Description section.